# Centering Ticks and Labels In The Middle Of Bar GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bar chart in ggplot, however, I cannot seem to get the labels and ticks to be in the center of the bar. Rather, the labels are to the right. I've tried hjust but it hasn't helped.

Here is how the chart looks:

[image]

To be clear, I'd like the label and axis of 2019-01 to be directly in the center of the red bar all the way to the right.

Here is the code creating the chart:

```
ggplot(data = earnings_returns, aes(x=date, y=return, fill=factor(sign(return)))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle(paste(ticker, 'Returns', 5, 'Day(s) After Announcement'))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")  + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

And code to create the dataframe:

```
earnings_returns <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17836, 17743, 17652, 17563, 
17472, 17379, 17288, 17197, 17099), class = "Date"), time = c(" AC", 
" AC", " AC", " AC", " AC", " AC", " AC", " AC", " AC"), ticker = c("AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL"
), price.close = c(222.220001, 190.289993, 169.100006, 167.779999, 
168.110001, 150.050003, 147.509995, 121.349998, 118.25), return = c(-0.0617855995779606, 
0.0883914478886969, 0.100236525124665, -0.0752771788966337, 0.0462197605959207, 
0.0668443772040446, 0.0439292944183205, 0.083889585230978, -0.0571670359408034
)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it is an issue with using dates. Changing them to factor fixed the issue:

[image]

```
ggplot(data = earnings_returns, aes(x=factor(date), y=return, fill=factor(sign(return)))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle(paste(ticker, 'Returns', 5, 'Day(s) After Announcement'))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")  + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Comment: Certainly a way of solving the centering, but be careful -- your x-axis is now a date but at irregularly spaced intervals. A naive observer could assume the number of days between each date is the same.To illustrate, use your original code and set `geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, width = 1)`